# Declaring a value as local once is slower than declaring it local each time

Tags: optimization, lua, local-variables

How is it possible that this piece of code:

```
local t
for n = 0, 255 do
    t = math.random(0, 255)
    ...
end
```

Is actually slower than this one?

```
for n = 0, 255 do
    local t = math.random(0, 255)
    ...
end
```

Since I am accessing `t` more than once in the `...` part, I am wondering, do `for` loops have their own set of local variables? If yes, is accessing a local variable from the current block faster than accessing one from the outer block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, declare variables as *local* as possible. And yes, `for` loop makes its own scope. It's the better coding style, and, as this example shows, usually more optimized.

Let's see what instructions the two pieces of code are generating, with `luac -l`

The first piece:

```
main <t.lua:0,0> (13 instructions at 00000000005e8260)
0+ params, 8 slots, 1 upvalue, 5 locals, 5 constants, 0 functions
        1       [1]     LOADNIL         0 0
        2       [2]     LOADK           1 -1    ; 0
        3       [2]     LOADK           2 -2    ; 255
        4       [2]     LOADK           3 -3    ; 1
        5       [2]     FORPREP         1 6     ; to 12
        6       [3]     GETTABUP        5 0 -4  ; _ENV "math"
        7       [3]     GETTABLE        5 5 -5  ; "random"
        8       [3]     LOADK           6 -1    ; 0
        9       [3]     LOADK           7 -2    ; 255
        10      [3]     CALL            5 3 2
        11      [3]     MOVE            0 5
        12      [2]     FORLOOP         1 -7    ; to 6
        13      [4]     RETURN          0 1
```

The second piece:

```
main <t.lua:0,0> (11 instructions at 0000000000538260)
0+ params, 7 slots, 1 upvalue, 5 locals, 5 constants, 0 functions
        1       [1]     LOADK           0 -1    ; 0
        2       [1]     LOADK           1 -2    ; 255
        3       [1]     LOADK           2 -3    ; 1
        4       [1]     FORPREP         0 5     ; to 10
        5       [2]     GETTABUP        4 0 -4  ; _ENV "math"
        6       [2]     GETTABLE        4 4 -5  ; "random"
        7       [2]     LOADK           5 -1    ; 0
        8       [2]     LOADK           6 -2    ; 255
        9       [2]     CALL            4 3 2
        10      [1]     FORLOOP         0 -6    ; to 5
        11      [3]     RETURN          0 1
```

As you can see. The first piece has two extra instructions. One of them is inside the loop:

```
        11      [3]     MOVE            0 5
```

What this does is to move the result in the register `5` (which has the result of `math.random`, to the register `0` (which is where the variable `t` is). And that answers your question.

Comment: Ok, so for loops have their own scope, and accessing a local variable from the outer scope is slower, but is accessing a local variable from the outer scope slower than accessing a global variable too?

Comment: I mean, is it viable, in the code above, to declare `local rand = math random` outside the loop, and then call `rand` inside the loop?

Comment: @user6245072 The answer is yes. If the loop is long, assigning the function to a local variable outside the loop has a better performance. Chapter 2 of [*Lua Programming Gems*](http://www.lua.org/gems/) talks about this in depth.

Comment: Never noticed that article. Cool.

Comment: @user6245072 Yes. In general, any time you indent in Lua is considered its own scope. That includes functions, do blocks, while/repeat/for loops

Comment: @DavisDude Yes, or more formally, everywhere "block" Is referenced in [The Complete Syntax of Lua](https://www.Lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9)